# Difference between ("hello" + 1) VS (*"hello") + 1 VS (*("hello" + 1))

Tags: c++, string, pointer-arithmetic

Ive been giving the following assignment to explain what is happening in 3 statements but i can't figure it out.

```
cout << ("hello" + 1);    // ello
cout << (*"hello") + 1;   // 105
cout << (*("hello" + 1)); // e
```

1. Why is number 2 a number instead of a character?
2. does first one still have zero character? (to end string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `*"hello"` gives the first character of the string, `'h'`, of type `char`, with ASCII value 104. The integer promotion rules means that, when adding `char` and `int`, the `char` is converted to `int`, giving a result of type `int`. Outputting an `int` gives the numeric value.
2. Yes. The string literal is an array ending with a zero character. Adding one to its address gives a pointer to the second character of the array; the remainder of the array is unchanged, so still contains the zero at the end.

Answer (score 6):

```
cout << ("hello" + 1);    // ello
```

You're incrementing a `const char[]` by 1, so you print everything but the first character (until you hit the null character

```
cout << (*"hello") + 1;   // 105
```

You dereference a `const char[]` here. The first character is an h, with ascii code `104`. Add one and you get `105`.

```
cout << (*("hello" + 1)); // e
```

Same thing as before, you dereference a `const char[]` but this time you increment by one first.

Comment: Worth noting that string literals are `const char[N]`s.

Comment: You can't dereference an array. You dereference the pointer the array decays into.

Answer (score 0):

"hello" is `const char *`.

1. Why 2 is number -> *"hello" will be value at base address that is ascii value of h(104), so 104 +1 = 105
2. Yes, you are just now pointing to `e` and not to `h`.

Comment: `"hello"` is `const char[6]`.

Comment: @chris string is literal I guess, so it can be const char*, but `const char[6]`?

Comment: Yes, you can see for yourself with `std::is_same`.